# Ordenar registro por distância baseado na latitude e longitude - Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

Teno uma tabela `companies` que tem um relacionamento polimorfico one to one com `addresses`
Tenho o parametro de `latitude` e `longitude` e gostaria de ordenar as companies pela distância da menor para maior. O SQL que tenho funciona corretamente se busco direto na tabela addresses, mas preciso que seja retornado as `companies`.

```
        $request['latitude'] = '-21.12633165824461';
        $request['longitude'] = '-47.766933831153125';

        $sqlDistance = DB::raw('( 111.045 * acos( cos( radians(' . $request['latitude'] . ') ) 
   * cos( radians( addresses.latitude ) ) 
   * cos( radians( addresses.longitude ) 
   - radians(' . $request['longitude'] . ') ) 
   + sin( radians(' . $request['latitude'] . ') ) 
   * sin( radians( addresses.latitude ) ) ) )');

        return $this->company->with(['bonusRule', 'address'])
            ->whereHas('address', function (Builder $query) use ($sqlDistance) {
                return $query->selectRaw("{$sqlDistance} AS distance")
                    ->orderBy('distance');
            })->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver, fica a solução para quem precisar:

```
    $request['latitude'] = '-21.12633165824461';
    $request['longitude'] = '-47.766933831153125';

        $sqlDistance = DB::raw('( 111.045 * acos( cos( radians(' . $request['latitude'] . ') ) 
   * cos( radians( addresses.latitude ) ) 
   * cos( radians( addresses.longitude ) 
   - radians(' . $request['longitude'] . ') ) 
   + sin( radians(' . $request['latitude'] . ') ) 
   * sin( radians( addresses.latitude ) ) ) )');

        return $this->company->selectRaw("companies.*, {$sqlDistance} AS distance")
            ->with(['bonusRule', 'address'])
            ->join('addresses', 'companies.id', '=', 'addresses.addressable_id')
            ->where('addresses.addressable_type', 'company')
            ->orderBy('distance')
            ->paginate(10);
```